# Find number of times employee attended meeting from Table Limit

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by, distinct, sql-limit

I have a table titled meetings managing the number of times an employee has been marked present for attending meetings for a range of dates. Table is just e_id and Date. If I have 50 Dates 2021-09-30, 2021-09-29... and an employee has been marked present 7 times in the table during the last 10 scheduled meetings, I am trying to show how many times the employee has been present for the last 10 meetings to determine a trend. For example, my query would look up the employee ID and display 7 for the example above. This is not working. I may have a typo. MYSQL states #1054 - Unknown column 'e_id' in 'field list'. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT COUNT(e_id) AS 'Present'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM meetings ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10) a
WHERE e_id = '".$sidw."'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery that you use to get the last 10 dates does not return the column `e_id` and this is why you get the *unknown column* error.

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can use `DENSE_RANK()` window function to get the rows of the last 10 dates and then aggregate:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Present
FROM (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) dr 
  FROM meetings 
) t
WHERE e_id = '".$sidw."' AND dr <= 10;
```

For previous versions use a join to the distinct dates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Present
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM meetings ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10) d
INNER JOIN meetings m ON m.date = d.date
WHERE m.e_id = '".$sidw."';
```

Comment: Thank you #forpas. Your solution was the homerun. Tested it out and it is showing the results I was expecting. I appreciate the speedy response and solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery syntax is wrong, for the result you want, you have to use the distinct SELECT as a WHERE/AND condition !

```
   SELECT COUNT(e_id) AS 'Present'
    FROM meetings
    WHERE e_id = '".$sidw."'
    AND Date IN (SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM meetings ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10)
```

Comment: MySql does not support LIMIT in subqueries used for the IN operator.

Comment: Thank you #Camile but MYSQL 5.5 did not support your solution.  Solution from #forpay worked for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because the inner query expose only the Date field, and not the e_id. You can modify it this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Present'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM meetings WHERE e_id = '".$sidw."' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10) a
```

You'll filter the e_id in the inner query, then do a count to whatever the inner query returns

Comment: @user3258571 This does not return *how many times the employee has been present for the last 10 meetings*.

Comment: It does not. i got overexcited. This is just returning the number of Present total and not limiting it to the last 10 meetings. Any additional help would be appreciated.